# When to add multiplayer to a game

Tags: networking, network-programming, multiplayer

Some friends and I are in the process of building a FPS wave survival shooter. A lot like Killing Floor actually. So the game is going to be mainly a multiplayer game. We currently have a basic framework for socket communication setup and a working world with physics where you can run around in.

So my question is when one is building such a multiplayer game should one build the network system along with the game development or should we create a working game with an entity/level/AI etc systems before adding a multiplayer system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your networking code is almost certainly going to be integral to your game engine. Write both at the same time; choices you make for one will inform related choices in the other.

Comment: It is certainly lack of experience that leads me to ask this question, but if I were to do it, I would have programmed to some networking / communication interface.  I would have factored in the multiplayer details from the beginning, like treating NPEs and human players the same.  Can you provide one or two concrete details to enlighten me?  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I figured that would most likely be the way to go. Thanks for the help.